# Issue with filling a rectangle with color in OcamlSDL

Tags: ocaml, sdl

I am trying to display a colored square in the center of a window in OcamlSDL. Creating the surface and the rectangle for the square and blitting it on the screen at the right position works without issue, however when I try to color the rectangle, only part of it gets colored (as seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjQAD.png) ).

Here is my code :

```
open Sdlevent
open Sdlkey
open Sdlvideo

let image_src = "background.jpg"
let win_x = 1200
let win_y = 800
let side = 10
let sq_size = 40
let seps = 10
let board_side = side * sq_size + seps * side
let o_x = (win_x - board_side) / 2
let o_y = (win_y - board_side) / 2
let f_x = o_x + board_side
let f_y = o_y + board_side

let rec event_handler () = match wait_event () with
    | KEYDOWN {keysym=KEY_ESCAPE} -> ()
    | event -> event_handler ()

let main () =
    Sdl.init [`VIDEO];
    at_exit Sdl.quit;
    let screen = Sdlvideo.set_video_mode win_x win_y [] in
    let bg = Sdlloader.load_image image_src in
    let pos_bg = Sdlvideo.rect 0 0 win_x win_y in
    Sdlvideo.blit_surface ~dst_rect:pos_bg ~src:bg ~dst:screen ();
    Printf.printf "board side = %d, o_x = %d, o_y = %d, f_x = %d, f_y = %d\n" board_side o_x o_y f_x f_y ;
    let board = Sdlvideo.create_RGB_surface [`HWSURFACE] board_side board_side 32 (Int32.of_int 0) (Int32.of_int 0) (Int32.of_int 0) (Int32.of_int 0) in
    let pos_board = Sdlvideo.rect o_x o_y f_x f_y in
    Sdlvideo.fill_rect ~rect:pos_board board (Int32.of_int 4294967295) ;
    Sdlvideo.blit_surface ~dst_rect:pos_board ~src:board ~dst:screen () ;
    Sdlvideo.flip screen;
    event_handler ()

let _ = main ()
```

I've looked around and haven't found any cases similar to mine, and OcamlSDL's documentation is of no help.
I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I have no idea what. Any suggestions ? This is on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

Comment: I dont't know Ocaml, but here is a few things to look at: when you create your rectangle (RGB surface) you are setting the Alpha channel as 0. It should be 1 to be fully visible. Another thing, what is up with the fill_rect function, you pass as argument a hard coded huge number. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: The color component masks used in the creation of RGB surfaces seems to work "backwards" : setting the alpha mask to the high value possible of an Int32 makes the surface completely transparent.

Comment: As for the fill_rect() function, it takes an Int32 (which is a specific type in ocaml) as color. I wasn't sure how this integer was going to be used "under the hood", so I specified the high value possible to get white (since I'm assuming it follows the RGBA color format).

Answer (score 0):

Look closer at the two lines below:

```
Sdlvideo.fill_rect ~rect:pos_board board (Int32.of_int 4294967295) ;
Sdlvideo.blit_surface ~dst_rect:pos_board ~src:board ~dst:screen () ;
```

You are filling a rectangle in your board offset by pos_board from the left upper edge. So only part of board is filled white. So now your board is a black rectangle with a white corner.

Then you blit the board onto the screen, again using an offset of pos_board. That puts the black retangle with white corner in the middle of the screen. Exactly as the screenshot shows.

If you want the whole board to be white then you have to use (0, 0) as upper left corner. Coordinates in board are relative.

Comment: It's been a few years since I've had a look at this code, but it looks like you're right. I'll test it out as soon as I can and accept your answer.